# Order processing

Tags: ruby

I have recently built a plain old Ruby program using TDD with RSpec to model this. I wanted to get feedback.

[Repo](https://github.com/benhawker/ruby-order-processing)

> For the company whose application we’re looking at, order processing
>   looks something like:
>
> If we accept an order over the web, then we have to wait for payment
>   to arrive, unless it’s a credit-card order. In the case of credit card
>   orders, we can process the order immediately and ship the goods, but
>   only if the goods are in stock. If they are not currently in stock, we
>   have to delay processing credit card orders until the become available
>   again.
>
> We can receive a check in payment of an existing order, in which case
>   we ship the goods (unless they are not in stock, in which case we hold
>   the check until the goods become available).
>
> We can receive a purchase order (PO) for a new order (we only accept
>   these from companies with an established credit account). In this case
>   we ship the goods (assuming they are in stock) and also generate an
>   invoice against the PO. At some point in the future we’ll receive
>   payment against this invoice and the order will be complete.
>
> At any time before the goods are shipped the customer may cancel an
>   order.
>
> Each step in this process may occur many days after the previous step.
>   For example, we may take an order over the web on Monday, receive a
>   check for this order on Thursday, then ship the goods and deposit the
>   check when the item is received from our own suppliers on the
>   following Tuesday.
>
> How can we design an application to support these kinds of rules?

```
class Customer
  VALID_TYPES = [:web, :company]

  attr_reader :name, :type

  def initialize(name, type)
    @name = name.to_s
    @type = type.to_sym

    validate!
  end

  private

  def validate!
    raise "This is not a valid type of customer" unless VALID_TYPES.include? self.type
  end
end
```

---

```
class Product

  attr_reader :title, :price
  attr_accessor :in_stock

  def initialize(title, price)
    @title = title.to_s
    @price = price.to_f.round(2)
    @in_stock = true
  end

  private 

  def in_stock?
    in_stock
  end

end
```

---

```
class Order

  VALID_STATUSES = [:pending, :paid, :shipped]

  attr_reader :customer
  attr_accessor :status, :total, :products

  def initialize(customer)
    @products = {}
    @status = :pending
    @customer = customer
  end

  def add_product(product, quantity = 1)
    @products[product] = (@products[product] ? @products[product] + quantity :  quantity )

    puts "You haved added #{quantity} #{product.title}'s to your order"
  end

  def show_order
    return products.map { |product, quantity| "Item: $#{product.price} / Quantity: #{quantity}\n" }
  end

  def order_total
    self.total = products.inject(0){|memo, (product, quantity)| (product.price * quantity) + memo}.to_f.round(2)
  end

  def change_status(status)
    raise "This is not a valid order status please try again" unless VALID_STATUSES.include? status
    self.status = status
  end

  def confirm_order(method_of_payment)
    if credit_card_but_products_out_stock?(method_of_payment)
      raise "Cannot make credit card payment now, as some products are out of stock" 
    end

    order_total
    Payment.new(method_of_payment, self.total)
  end

  def self.from_purchase_order(purchase_order)
    new(purchase_order.customer) do |order|
      order.products = purchase_order.products.clone
    end
  end

  private

  def credit_card_but_products_out_stock?(method_of_payment)
    true if method_of_payment == :credit_card && !all_products_in_stock?
  end

  def all_products_in_stock?
    count = @products.select { |product| product.in_stock == false }.size
    count == 0 ? true : false
  end

end
```

---

```
class Invoice

  attr_reader :customer
  attr_accessor :total, :products

  def initialize(customer, products)
    @products = {}
    @customer = customer
    @payment_recieved = false
  end

  def show_invoice
    return products.map { |product, quantity| "Item: $#{product.price} / Quantity: #{quantity}\n" }
  end

  def self.from_purchase_order(purchase_order)
    new(purchase_order.customer, purchase_order.products.clone)
  end

end
```

---

```
class PurchaseOrder

  attr_reader :customer, :products
  attr_accessor :total

  def initialize(customer)
    @products = {}
    @customer = customer

    validate!
  end

  def add_product(product, quantity = 1)
    @products[product] = (@products[product] ? @products[product] + quantity :  quantity )

    puts "You haved added #{quantity} #{product.title}'s to your purchase order"
  end

  def show_purchase_order
    return products.map { |product, quantity| "Item: $#{product.price} / Quantity: #{quantity}\n" }
  end

  def purchase_order_total
    self.total = products.inject(0){|memo, (product, quantity)| (product.price * quantity) + memo}.to_f.round(2)
  end

  def confirm_purchase_order 
    purchase_order_total 
    raise "Your PO appears to be empty! Add some products and try again." unless self.total.to_f.round(2) > 0

    create_order
    create_invoice

    return "We have generated an Invoice and created an order."
  end

  def create_order
    Order.from_purchase_order(self)
  end

  def create_invoice
    Invoice.from_purchase_order(self)
  end

  private

  def validate!
    raise "Customer must be a company account" unless customer.type == :company
  end

end
```

---

```
class Payment

  VALID_METHODS_OF_PAYMENT = [:credit_card, :check]

  attr_accessor :method_of_payment, :amount

  def initialize(method_of_payment, amount)
    @method_of_payment = method_of_payment
    @amount = amount

    validate!
  end

  private

  def validate!
    raise "This is not a valid payment method" unless VALID_METHODS_OF_PAYMENT.include? self.method_of_payment
    raise "Uh oh, your order appears to be empty" unless self.amount.to_f.round(2) > 0
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

I only spotted a few lines of code that could be nicer, otherwise it's
readable:

- `count == 0 ? true : false` is `count == 0`, which is `count.zero?`.
- Similarly,
  `true if method_of_payment == :credit_card && !all_products_in_stock?`
  should simply be
  `method_of_payment == :credit_card && !all_products_in_stock?`.
- If this was production code I'd strongly advice you to use proper
  decimal numbers
  (i.e. [`BigDecimal`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html))
  instead of floats for monetary values.

The formatting is sometimes inconsistent and the choice of printing
messages vs. returning strings is also not consistently applied - I'd go
for one or the other and stick with it.

Otherwise I think looks okay; maybe consider refactoring common code
into some shared thing, i.e. the `show_` methods.

Comment: Thanks for your points. I had not realised the importance of using BigDecimal (or rather not using floats for monetary values before) so have been reading up on that. Good resource on it (https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/08/14/currency-rounding-errors/).